How did early chemists work out the number of protons in the nucleus?
I was reading about the history of the periodic table and the description of an element’s atomic number as its proton number. I couldn’t find the source again but it was stated that they figured out each element’s proton number because it’s equal to that element’s nucleus’ electric charge. So, how do you measure an element’s nucleus’ electric charge?

They didn't have the means for that back then - it would involve fully ionising it. That atomic number is its proton number was found thanks to Moseley's law

Atoms are neutral. If one knows the number of electrons, one knows the number of protons. See how Mosely relate3d spectral lines to number of electrons, for example.

How does one fully ionize an atom and was that technology invented later? @mithoron

You just pump it enough energy, with laser, maser, or whatever. Then you could tell it's charge from behaviour in magnetic field. Accelerators use fully stripped nuclei all the time.

Might be worth rephrasing to "how did early chemists work out the number of protons in the nucleus".

The allusion to Moseley's contributions in the comments is only partially correct in a historical sense. It was Antonius van den Broek (a name rarely mentioned in general chemistry) who proposed that the atomic number corresponds to the charge of the atomic nucleus.
See his single paragraph influential letter: Van den Broek, Antonius. "The Number of Possible Elements and Mendeléff's “Cubic” Periodic System." Nature 87.2177 (1911): 78-78.
Link

The Number of Possible Elements and Mendeléeff's "Cubic" Periodic
System. According to Rutherford's theory of "single scattering" ("On
the Scattering of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ Particles by Matter and the
Structure of the Atom," Phil. Mag., May, I9II), and to Barkla's "Note
on the Energy of Scattered X-Radiation" (ibid.), the numbers of
electrons per atom is half the atomic weight; thus, for $U$, about 120
. Now, a reconstruction of Mendeléeff's " cubic" periodic sy:stem, as
suggested in his famous paper "Die Beziehungen zwischen den
Eigenschaften der Elemente und ihren Atomgewichten " (Ostw. Klass.,
No. 68, pp. 32, 36, 37, and 74), gives a constant mean difference
between consecutive atomic weights $=2$, and thus, from $H$ to $U,
> 120$ as the number of possible elements (van den Broek, "Das
Mendelejeff'sche 'Kubische' Periodische System der Elemente und die
Einordnung der Radioelemente in dieses System," Physik. Zeitschr. I2,
p. 490). Hence, if this cubic periodic system should prove to be
correct, then the number of possible elements is equal to the number
of possible permanent charges of each sign per atom, or to each
possible permanent charge (of both signs) per atom belongs a possible
element.
Noordwijk-Zee, June 23. A. VAN DEN BROEK.


The key point of Moseley's work is that he showed that something observable (the frequency of X-ray emissions from nuclei) told us something about the composition of the nucleus. This made sense if atomic number (previously based on ordering elements by mass with some adjustments for chemical similarity) was based on some observable nuclear feature that matched the atomic number. Other known observations combined suggested this feature was the nuclear charge. Actually creating fully ionised nuclei wasn't necessary.

@AChem May you add the name of journal of the publication, or/and a doi?
